# Properties of roots

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

I've been struggling to understand the procedure shown below. Somehow, by setting x=0 I managed to get to the equation (1.12). However, I think didn't get it really as I do not know how to compare the coefficients (which is apparently important to get to (1.13) ).

[image: Screenshot]

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

> I think didn't get it really as I do not know how to compare the coefficients

All it means is that $\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i=\sum_{i=0}^n b_ix^i$ if and only if $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$. "Setting $x=0$" is one way of looking at the constant term of a polynomial, but it's not really necessary if you follow the fact I just mentioned.

You're presented with three ways of writing polynomials, but if you multiply them out, their coefficients have to match. The first equation gives you labels for the coefficients ($a_i$) and the latter two, if multiplied out, will give you coefficients in terms of $\alpha_i$, the roots.

The author's point is that the $a_0$ and $a_{n-1}$, are easy to compute in terms of the roots, but it is not very useful to compute the rest of the coefficients this way.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Could you please elaborate in a step-by-step explanation how you get to the desired result? I might have missed the point by trying to multiply the third equation out (as n can be very large).

Comment: @MrDerDart No, I'm not going to do that for you: multiplying the third one out is the *entire point*.  Just ask yourself "after this mess gets multiplied out, what are all the things that look like $\lambda x^{n-1}$ for some scalar $\lambda$? Gather those up, and you have your solution.  Perhaps you should just start out with toy examples to convince yourself how it works: take $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ and try that first.  It's not that hard... you don't have to ask strangers to do it!

Comment: After carefully multiplying out the third equation with n = 5, I finally noticed the pattern and hence, I got to the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you have a product of binomials like these
$$
\alpha_n(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\dotsm(x-\alpha_n)=0
$$
Which for simplicity we are going to convert it to a monic polynomial:
$$(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\dotsm(x-\alpha_n)=0$$
You can express it also like this:
$$
(x-\alpha_j)\prod_{i\neq j}^n{}(x-\alpha_i)\iff 1\le j \le n
$$
Now lets expand $\prod_{i\neq j}^n{}(x-\alpha_i)$:
$$
(x-\alpha_j)(x^{n-1} + b_{n-2}x^{n-2} + b_{n-3}x^{n-3} + \dots  + b_{1}x + b_{0}) = x(x^{n-1} + b_{n-2}x^{n-2} + b_{n-3}x^{n-3} + \dots  + b_{1}x + b_{0}) 
-
 \alpha_j(x^{n-1} + b_{n-2}x^{n-2} + b_{n-3}x^{n-3} + \dots  + b_{1}x + b_{0})
$$
After expanding the equation from above we focus on the term $ (b_{n-2}-\alpha_j)x^{n-1} $.

Now we need to figure out what $b_{n-2}$ is. Lets start with the first two cases.

***I am going to omit non-relevant terms just for simplicity.***

**For n = 2:**
$$
(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2) = x^2+(-\alpha_1-\alpha_2)x+\alpha_1\alpha_2
$$

**For n = 3:**
$$
(x-\alpha_1)(x^2+(-\alpha_2-\alpha_3)x+\alpha_2\alpha_3) = 
x^3+(-\alpha_1-\alpha_2-\alpha_3)x^2 +...-\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3
$$

From this part it is easy to see that $b_{n-2} = b_{n-3}-\alpha_{n}$ where $b_{0} = -\alpha_2$.

That implies $a_{n-1}=b_{n-2}-\alpha_1=-(\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3+..+\alpha_n)=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\alpha_k}$

$$a_{n-1}=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\alpha_k}\to -a_{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\alpha_k}$$

Now remember that the polynomial equation given in the picture is not necessarily monic so we fix that by dividing the left side of the equation by $a_n$.
$$-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\alpha_k}$$